# Вы – учитель, а не ученик

Tags: тире

В справочнике Лопатина говорится, что тире нужно ставить, когда подлежащие выражено местоимением, если есть противопоставление. Однако там есть только такой пример, как, например, такой: *Вы – учитель, а он – ученик; Я – кот, а ты – пёс-собачонка.* Поэтому я бы-с хотел, чтобы вы мне сказали, нужно ли тире тоже, например, при такой конструкции:

1. Вы – учитель, а не ученик.
2. Он – ребёнок, а не взрослый таки.
3. Я – твой дед, а не папа.

Лопатин: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106.